# How to change NSDateFormatter for a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string which has date field in it. I am storing the field as NSString in my database like 2011-12-07 21:15:00 +0000.

I am using the following code to get the date from the string in the date format like :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];
```

I want the above date format in the time format as hh a but it always gives null.
My code :

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"hh a"];

    [dateFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease] ];
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:startSection];

    NSLog(@"Date 1 : %@", date1);


    [timeFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease] ];
    NSDate *time1 = [timeFormat dateFromString:startSection];
    NSString *strSection2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", time1];
    NSLog(@"Time 1 : %@", strSection2); /// always null at this place.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Can anybody help me out here ?

Comment: Hey there! Did you try out what i suggested? Does it work for you?

Comment: Hi Phlibbo.Thanks for your help. But mine is more than just looking into date. I have to sort a string which I have to write a code for.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand a word of your last comment :/

Comment: So just to get this straight: You are reading a string which is supposed to be in the format @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S". That didn't work for you, I told you why. Then you want to save this date in another format? (hh a)? If this is not correct, you might want to give us more information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Show the output when you run this code that would be helpful. But if I had to guess you are doing something wrong in the time format part. I would suggest you get your date from the database string, using the date formatter as you have it, and at this point in the code:
(Which I am assuming works)

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease] ];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:startSection];

NSLog(@"Date 1 : %@", date1);
```

Switch gears after the above code and do this instead too get your time in a string in the format desired:

```
[timeFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease] ];
NSString * time = [timeFormat stringWithDate:date1];
NSLog(@"Time 1 : %@", time);
```

Comment: I am sure I can do that and get the value of timeFormat in NSString. But my worries is when I do sorting on the date on nsstring it gives wrong output. Hence I was looking to change it ti NSDate such that sorting of the dates is correct.

Comment: Either sort on the processed string as I created above or set up your sort specifically to what you wish to sort on with the NSDate. Date is a date is a date, what you format is of no consequence to the NSDate. I can't guess what you mean about sorting but with respect to dates I would think ascending and descending would be the only meaningful methods, and for that you do not need to do any of this formatting. If you wish to sort on hour alone use the string after formatting.

Comment: I have used the hour alone as a string and then I added in an array and found out that it does not sort correctly as it gets sorted while running the query. I get the following output : Array: {10AM,
    11AM,
    8AM}          How to change the following array sort? I am currently using sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:).

Comment: Well the classic problem of sorting numbers still exists. Try going to 24 hour clock and then just grab the hour and turn that into an integer. (i.e. you probably don't want to hassle of sorting numbers and the AM/PM tag, just convert to 24 hour clock, makes it easier)

Comment: Actually my problem is little bigger. I am trying to create sections through the array of dates by inserting the values as keys in NSDictionary and respective values associated. When I run the query I get the dates sorted but when I add in Dictionary it some how gets unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

Your date goes `2011-12-07 21:15:00 +0000` while your formatString goes `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"`. The `ss.S` is the problem here. Make it `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +S"` and it'll work.

With regards to the time format, I am not sure what you are doing. You are obviously passing the same string to it (`startSection`) which doesn't even look close to `hh a`.

**Update:** Oh, and if I am not mistaking, the formatting follows [this conventions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) which means that you are probably looking for Z and not for S.